# Coding on a Live Server using Angular

Tags: angular

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 as my development server which is hosted in the cloud. What I do is I connect to my server directly whenever I try to edit codes. This also helps me do my job anywhere and anytime.

I don't have a problem doing this with PHP. Recently, I've decided to use angular as my front-end framework. Doing this locally and development on my **localhost:4200** is not a problem. This doesn't seem to pose any problem locally since loading is fast but when I uploaded it on the my staging server wherein I directly do the coding. Loading is extremely slow. I can't use build and production mode since I am doing the coding in this server.

Is there a way to optimize the loading?

The command I use is

```
ng serve --host 128.199.XXX.XXX
```

The IP Address is Cloud Server

Comment: why ARE you coding on a live server?

Comment: You code on your local machine, and then deploy it on the server

Comment: @AyushGupta I understand that what you are saying is the best solution to go. I just want to do it in the cloud. The cloud server is not my live server for my clients. It's just mine.

Comment: Coding on a live server means you will always face network latency, there's no getting aroung that

Comment: @AyushGupta I'm not pertaining to a normal latency I encountered. I've been doing this for 3 years in PHP. I recently just encountered this with Angular.

Comment: try using ng build --prod

Comment: Is the loading slow or the detection of changes slow, as in start of loading?

Comment: try using npm run build -- --prod --env=prod

Answer (score 0):

PHP is interpreted, ie. not compiled. Angular is compiled (or transpiled and bundled). That takes a bit of time, and if your cloud server instance isn't as fast as your desktop or laptop or doesn't have plenty of memory, it'll take even more time.

Also, if you mean the app bootstrap is slow, yeah with Angular there's not only the network lag, there's also the time it takes to bootstrap the Javascript, which is slow when you `ng serve`. Faster when you `ng build --prod` because it'll be compiled and optimized ahead of time.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. I think there is no way to this but do it in the local server. Thanks